# Oracle SQL Query IN

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following query, that's not working.

```
select * from table where id in (
   1,2, (select id from another_table)
)
```

How i can rewrite it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
select * from table 
where id in (1,2)
   or id in (select id from another_table)
```

Take care and use parentheses when adding additional `WHERE`-conditions using `and`!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from table 
where id in (1,2) OR id in(
   select id from another_table
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where id in (
select 1 as id from dual
union all
select 2 as id from dual
union all
select id from another_table
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where id in (
   select 1 from dual
     union all
   select 2 from dual
     union all
   select id from another_table);
```

I'm using union because this is faster than using an OR clause which also can be used.